# How to use DSL modem along with router to have two external IPs

Tags: networking, dhcp, dsl

I had an issue with my DSL connection (I have CenturyLink) and after talking to one of the line engineers at Centurylink he mentioned that per DSL line, you were allowed two external IPs. He said if you put the modem in bridged mode and hooked a computer up it would get an external IP.

I have an AirPort Extreme that I'd like to hook up after the DSL modem and have it act as the DHCP server, so it would get one public IP but I'd like my main PC to get the other public IP.

How can I do this? I was thinking possibly Modem -> Wired switch -> Airport Extreme with my main PC hooked up to the wired switch. But then I've got the router's firewall between my PC and the rest of my home network which would be a big pain.

Comment: Do you want the PC to have a public routable IP, or a private IP that is NAT'd by the AirPort Extreme?

Comment: I'd like my main PC to have a public routable IP and all other PCs on my home network to have private IPs handed out by the AirPort.

Answer (score 1):

If you require more than one public IP address you will need to discuss it with your ISP. Whether your modem can deal with it is another matter but your ISP should be able to advise you about that as well.

Most importantly, you should ask your engineer to stick to his own field.

Comment: Um, that is his field?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. Put the modem in bridged mode and connect it to a wired switch. Connect to that switch *only* the two devices you want to get public IP addresses.